# MongoDB filter inner array of object

Tags: mongodb, database

I have one document like this:

```
-document: users-
{
"name": "x", password: "x" recipes: 
[{title: eggs, dificult: 1},{title: "pizza" dificult: 2}],
name: "y", password: "y" recipes: [{title: "oil", dificult: 2},{title: "eggandpotatoes" dificult: 2}]
}
```

I want to get all recipes filtering by title and dificult

I have tried some like this

```
db.users.find({$and: [{"recipes.title": /.*egg.*/},{"recipes.dificult": 2}]}, 
{"recipes.title": 1,"recipes.dificult": 1}).toArray();
```

this should return

```
{title: "eggandpotatoes" dificult: 2}
```

but return

```
{title: eggs, dificult: 1}
{title: "eggandpotatoes" dificult: 2}
```

I would like once the filter works, limit the result with start: 2 and end: 5
returning from the 2 result the next 5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ***[$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)*** aggregation to filter the recipes and ***[$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)*** to limit the results. It will give you everything you are looking expect but regex search which is not possible as of now.

```
db.users.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        recipes: {
            $slice: [{
                $filter: {
                    input: "$recipes",
                    as: "recipe",
                    "cond": {
                        $and: [{
                            $eq: ["$$recipe.title", "eggandpotatoes"]
                        }, {
                            $eq: ["$$recipe.dificult", 2]
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }, 2, 3]
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find out regular expression in `title` then use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) as below :

```
db.users.find({"recipes":{"$elemMatch":{"title": /.*egg.*/,"dificult": 2}}}, {"recipes.$":1})
```

One thing I mentioned here if your `recipes` array contains some thing like this

`"recipes" : [ { "title" : "egg", "dificult" : 2 }, { "title" : "eggand", "dificult" : 2 } ]`

then **[$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)** projection return only first matched array objcect in above case it will be

`"recipes" : [ { "title" : "egg", "dificult" : 2 } ]`

If you need this both array then go to **@Sagar** answer using aggregation